# mongoose findone inside For loop

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to iterate through a for loop. While I am inside the loop for each iteration, i want to search the values in a collection and then consequently save it another collection. The problem is it waits for the entire set of values to get over before and tries to search the collection for the last pair of records. Whereas my requirement is that i want it to do the search right from the start. Here is the code so far.

```
for(i=0; i<namearray.length-1; ){
              player1 = namearray[i];
              console.log("Hi i am Player 1", player1)
              for(j=1; j<namearray.length; ){
                if(j <= i){
                  j = i;
                  j++;
                  continue;
                }
                player2 = namearray[j]
                console.log("Hi i am player 2", player2)
                tournamentMatchRegister.findOne({$and:[{$or:[{Player1_Name : player1}, {Player2_Name : player2}]},
                    {$or:[{Player1_Name : player2}, {Player2_Name : player1}]}]},(function(err,data2){
                      if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                      } else {
                        console.log(data2)
                        console.log("Hi I am here")
                        console.log("Hi i am ", player1)
                        console.log("Hi i am ", player2)
                        if(data2.Match_Completed === "No"){
                          var newpotentialmatch = new scheduleRegister({
                            Week_Number: weeknumber,
                            Player1_Name: player1,
                            Player1_Team: data2.Player1_TeamName,
                            Player1_Seed: data2.PlayerSeedLevel,
                            Player2_Name: player2,
                            Player2_Team: data2.Player2_TeamName,
                            Player2_Seed: data2.PlayerSeedLevel
                          }); newpotentialmatch.save(function(err,data3){
                            if(err){
                              console.log(err)
                            }
                          })
                        }
                     }
                }))
                    j++
              }
              i++
            }
```

Any reason why its behaving like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` to achieve this.

Pay attention to use `async` keyword before your function definition:

```js
let loop = async function () {
  // First loop
  ..
  .
  ..
  for (i = 0; i < namearray.length - 1; ) {
    ..
    .
    ..
    let data2 = await tournamentMatchRegister.findOne({
    $and:[{
            $or:[{
                   Player1_Name : player1
                 }, {
                   Player2_Name : player2}
                 ]},
                    {
                      $or:[{
                             Player1_Name : player2
                           }, {
                             Player2_Name : player1
                           }
                ]}
         ]}
    }
    ..
    .
    ..
}
```